# Exporting Output issue (Netlogo)

Tags: csv, netlogo

I am having problems with exporting the data from one of the models that I have built. My intention was to export the values for each of the variables, or atleast the key ones for each iteration (as these will be updated each go procedure). I have tried using `export-world` but my problem is that it will not store the values for each of the variables for each iteration but rather just one value and overwrite the .csv sheet. Is there anyway to create a .csv sheet where the variable values for each iteration will stack up in columns? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that [BehaviorSpace](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/behaviorspace.html) is exactly what you're looking for. It allows you to run your model, possibly many times with different parameters, and will record the results in a csv file. It's built into NetLogo.

Answer (score 2):

File Output Example, in the Code Examples section of the NetLogo Models Library, has sample code for this. It doesn't use commas to separate the values, but you can tweak it to do that.

It would be easier to use BehaviorSpace, though, as Bryan suggests.